# Create directory in vifm

Tags: linux, vifm

I use vifm as my file manager occasionally and was wondering how to create a new directory?!

Both vifm -h and man vifm are pretty short and don't really help..

EDIT: Just noticed that in the MINT repros there only seems to be vifm version 0.4... :-S

Comment: As Linux Mint is Ubuntu/Debian based, maybe you can just install Vifm 0.7.8 from [Debian testing](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/vifm).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To create a directory:

```
:mkdir <dirname>
```

Answer (score 3):

*(sorry, not enough rep to add a comment on DavidPostill post)*

I found for v.0.4 the command had to be

```
:!mkdir <dirname>
```